# Apple Watch Series 4 complications

Tags: apple-watch, apple-watch-complication, watchos-5

When creating complication images for old complications, we can see all 4 sizes:

[image: Old complication image]

But when I wanted to add images to new complications for Series 4, there are only 1 size?

[image: New complication image]

The documentation (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/icons-and-images/complication-images/) stated that we need to support both 40/44mm, but how?

Comment: The real answer is that it has to be saved as PDF file and use the 40/42mm version, not 38 or 44.

Answer (score 0):

They are all the same icon. They all are looking for the x2 graphic to support their resolution. I would recommend using the 44mm as your x2 and let xCode scale it down when needed.

If you look at the documentation, at the end of each resolution it tells your which asset x1, x2, or x3 that it is searching for. They all search for x2.

Edit: OP has figured out that the icons have to be saved as PDF file and use the 40mm/42mm version, not 38mm or 44mm. Adding here for anyone else who is having a similar issue.

Comment: The size are different for 40 and 44mm (one is 40x40, one is 44x44). In old complications, I need to provide different sizes for 38/40/42/44mm, and what you say is I can just ignore 40mm and go straight for 44mm?

Comment: Essentially, yes. xCode will automatically scale down to what it needs. You may have noticed that x1 has started to be phasing out because devices no longer support that small of a resolution. In this case, they are only giving you x2 because that's all you need.

Comment: It is not a x1 vs x2 problem. It is which x2 images to use. I did try 44x44 (the larger size), and it does not work.

Comment: What is your implementation? Here is reference by Apple stating to let the resizing do the work: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/icons-and-images/image-optimizations/  Your implementation on how you are assigning the image asset might be the issue.

Comment: The links help. The real answer is that it has to be saved as PDF file and use the 40/42mm version, not 38 or 44.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I edited the answer just for the ease of access for anyone else having the issue. I hoped I was able to assist you a little bit in finding your solution. :)